# Unable to run client side validation without submitting form

Tags: asp.net, .net, validation, razor-pages

I'm trying to trigget client-side validation without submitting my form. I thought the following line would do it.

```
form.validate();
```

But this does nothing. No validation errors are shown. And there are no JavaScript errors. (And I verified `form` is not an empty jQuery object.)

If I submit my form, the expected validation errors are shown so my form seems to be correct. Am I missing something? What else can I check?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery validation has two steps. The first is to call `validate()`, as I did in my question. The second is to call `valid()`, which returns a boolean value that indicates whether or not the form is valid.

Unexpectedly, it is the call to `valid()` that causes the validation errors to be displayed.

So, even though my code wasn't interested in whether or not validation was successful, it still needs to call `valid()` in order to display validation errors.